# Listener for DatePickerDialog +/- button

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I'm currently using `DatePickerDialog` in my Android app.

As everyone, knows the dialog has three `EditText`s: 1) for day 2) for month 3) for year. And there are + and - buttons for the three to move to front and back of the selected field. I need to know if there exists any listener for the "+" and "-" buttons in the dialog?

This is because, in my app, I don't want the user to select previous dates before the current date using the dialog. So if the "-" button is clicked, it should check whether the date in the dialog is less than the current date. So I need a listener for the "-" button of the dialog.

Also I'm developing this app for all platforms starting from Froyo to KitKat. I have heard that there is a `setMinDate()` for `DatePicker`. But it is available only from HoneyComb.

Comment: Try to make custom DatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog and try to handle your date restriction in Overrided onDateChanged().

Comment: plase check this link https://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try overriding `onDateChnaged()` function, here is example:
`DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
                    // this function will call when user click on '+' or '-'. Apply validation here. you can call view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay); if u don't want to accept date that user trying to select by pressing +/- 
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    /* this validation allow user to enter date less then current date */
                    if (year > mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);`

```
                if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear)
                    view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                    view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            }
        };
```

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
            // Add your code here to handle selected date event by user

}
};

Comment: How to check if the selected date is less than current date? Can you please code me the steps.. I tried but, I didn't get it..That's why I asked you..

Comment: inside `onDateChanged()` function get current Year, month and date and compare it with year, monthofyear and dayofmonth parameter you received in function

Comment: Your code works fine, but there is some minor problem in it. There is a textview showing the date, in this format: Monday, 18/Aug/2014 above the datepicker dialog. When a user clicks on - button, it should not move to 17/Aug/2014. This was my condition to check. The date in the three columns are not changing when a user clicks on - button of the dialog, but the textview displays Sunday, 17/Aug/2014 as soon as - button is clicked. But when the - button is further clicked, it doesnot change the text in the textview. This is a minor bug in it. How can it be solved??

Comment: What I mean is that DatePickerDialog.updateDate() does not update the title of the dialog. See this link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1802

Answer (score 0):

You really cant implement `setMinDate` for api under `honeyComb`, but you can still use a backported `datePickerDialog` that is design to have `setMinDate` method functionality just within it that will work from `froyo` and above you can check this [github project](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker).

Use that project as a `DatePicker` dialog for froyo till honeyComb, and use the regular default `DatePicker` of android for honeycomb and above.